# How can I express the rules of this game clearly?

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

This is the information:

There are many mixed couples playing in this game. One of the couple must award *vote 1*, *2* or *3* to the opposite sex e.g., a male *votes 1* to a female.

- A couple is a male and a female
- Winning Couple: The male in that couple has to *vote 1* to his female partner.

For example; **Couple A** is male A and female A ,  **Couple B** is male B and female B etc.

The winning couple A is the one in which male A *voted 1* to female A and female A *voted 1* to her male partner.

- So does the sentence below express correctly the above information?

> the winning couple is the one that has both male and female voted 1 to each other

Comment: This is very unclear to me. What is the game play? Are people voting for anybody, but they happen to all be in couples, and the idea is that you want your own couple to win? And the criterion to win is if the members of a couple vote for each other? Wouldn't everybody knowing this simply vote for their partner and then everybody would win?

Comment: there are many males & females playing the game if a male vote 1 to a female then they are the winning couple

Comment: You keep adding rules to your game in comments so the main question is both unclear and incomplete. How about writing it the _entire_ set of rules _clearly_ in your native language before entirely rewriting the question about it that you want to ask.

Comment: See my question

Comment: If those are the rules the **competition** won't last very long. As soon as anyone can "vote" they will automatically vote for their partner.

Comment: I deleted the title suggested by a user which was NOT the OP's original one, and, in  my opinion, was also misleading.

Comment: My interpretation is that there is a mixed group of people *who are NOT currently couples*. Each one of the group must vote for another member of the group who is the opposite sex. If ManA votes for WomanC AND WomanC votes for ManA, they are a winning couple. But if ManA votes for WomanB and WomanB votes for ManD, they do not form a couple and do not win.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The winner is the couple ***whose*** partners have "voted" for each other.

The expression *the winning couple* is ambiguous; it could mean a couple is currently in the lead or a particular couple is endearing, charming, delightful etc. as well as meaning *victorious*.

I placed *voted* in inverted commas because it's unclear to *me* how the ***points*** (?) are awarded in this game. If the game really has a voting system, then leave out the inverted commas.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how that method would select a unique winner, as it seems any number of couples could vote for each other.  Also, you don't say how many votes each participant is allowed. I suggest: "The winning couple is the one where the man and woman (boy and girl?) voted for each other.  Note that you wouldn't say "voted 1 to", but you could say "gave one vote to"

Comment: there are 3 level of voting -1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

Might be simpler to use the word "each" instead of "both". "The couple wins if each member receives one vote."

Answer (score 0):

A pair wins if each member voted for the other.